# Mac how to delete broken symlink in Mac trash

Tags: macos, terminal, symlink

In the Trash folder on my Mac I have the following directory that contains a symlink I can't delete called X11R6 (`/Users/gcn/.Trash/temp/Previously Relocated Items/Security/usr/`).

I've tried a variety of things (`rm`, `unlink`, etc). This is the most recent `sudo find . -type l -delete` The error message from this is `find: -delete: unlink(./X11R6): Operation not permitted`

`ls -l` returns `total 0 lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  8 Jul 21  2019 X11R6 -> /opt/X11`

What do I need to do differently?

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/441540/22769 and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/374939/22769

Comment: See if this can help you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/461624/119271

Comment: Can you run `cd "/Users/gcn/.Trash/temp/Previously Relocated Items/Security"; ls -l@eOd usr usr/X11R6` and add the result to the question?

Comment: `drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  -          96 Jul  8 13:39 usr
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  restricted  8 Jul 21  2019 usr/X11R6 -> /opt/X11`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directions in [Can't remove file from trash](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/374939/cant-remove-file-from-trash) work fine except that on my M1 Mac, booting into recovery mode is done by turning off the Mac, then holding the power key down until a couple of icons show up. Click the one that is not your hard disk icon, login, and choose terminal from the menu options. Follow the directions from there.